# Connecting instruments and virtual amps to ardour in Ubuntu studio

Tags: music, ubuntu-studio, midi, ardour

I am using Ubuntu studio19.04. I have Behringer 320usb interface. I wish to connect my guitar to the guitarix virtual amp and record it using ardour. But I can't figure out how to connect guitarix and hydrogen to ardour. 
Please help me out
Thank you

Comment: Since Ubuntu (Studio) 19.04 support ends in one month, I highly recommend upgrading to 19.10 at this time. Failure to do so will result in the inability to upgrade normally and will require a much more convoluted method to upgrade.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple.

1. Use [Ubuntu Studio Controls](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/UbuntuStudioControls) and make sure Jack is running.
2. Launch Hydrogen, Guitarix, Ardour, **and Carla**
3. Set Ardour, Guitarix, and Hydrogen to your needs.
4. Click on the Patchbay tab in Carla. Connect Hydrogen and Guitarix to Ardour by dragging lines (think as if it were a physical cable) from the output on Guitarix and Hydrogen to Ardour.
5. ???
6. Profit!

That's all there is to it. :)

Comment: I like the South Park reference. :)